# Format price using javascript (preferably jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a site that is outputting price like so: KD45.000
What I would like to do is show the KD and the 3 zeros after the decimal point at half the height of the 45. 
Thanks
Adam

Comment: No need for a downvote ??? the OP asked a reasonable question and its their first - perhaps comment on how they could improve their question before downvoting ....

Comment: Do you want the decimal to round up or down?

Answer (score 2):

no javascript just html

<sup>KD</sup>45<sup>.000</sup>

Code:

```
 <sup>KD</sup>45<sup>.000</sup>
```

Comment: Normally I would change the underlying code accordingly. However in this case I can not. So I need to look at doing something after the price has been rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string using `.split('.')` into two parts. Output the segments like so:

```
<sup>KD</sup>{segment1}<sup>.{segment2}</sup>
```

Comment: Thanks Blender. Don't know why I didn't think of that myself. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a complete solution for what you're trying to do:

```
function FormatPrice(price) {
  price = price.split('.');
  return '<sub>' + (price[0] || 0) + '</sub>.' + (price[1] || '000');
}
```

Originally: KD45.000

FormatPrice('45.000'): KD<sub>45</sub>.000